# Compiling systrace gives "two or more data types in declaration specifiers"

Tags: c, ubuntu, libevent

I have been trying to compile systrace (1.6g) on Ubuntu. When I am using libevent 2.0.16, I get the following compilation error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/netdb.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/event2/util.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/evutil.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/event.h:57,
                 from systrace.c:67:
/usr/include/netinet/in.h:141: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
/usr/include/netinet/in.h:141: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
```

These are the corresponding lines in /usr/include/netinet/in.h:

```
/* Internet address.  */
typedef uint32_t in_addr_t;
struct in_addr
  {
    in_addr_t s_addr;
  };
```

Can anyone provide any insight on what I could change in netinet/in.h to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look into `config.h` (created by running `./configure`) and find the line

```
#define in_addr_t unsigned long
```

Comment it out  (or delete it) and you might at least get further in compiling this obviously somehow broken package.

---

Just a guess: As systrace 1.6g is quiet old it might be necessary to use libevent 1.x.y to compile it.

You might like to download the current libevent 1 package [here](https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-1.4.14b-stable.tar.gz).

Comment: Using libevent-1.4.14b-stable gives this error message when I run make: http://pastie.org/3137269 .  Same result with libevent-1.0e. I also tried using gcc-3.4, when I use it even libevent 2.0.16 gives the same error message in the pastie. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: my `config.h` contains two of this lines and removing them make it works